# What do I do about a file that was literally split into two while moving it?

Tags: data-recovery, crash, filemanager, ubuntu-mate, caja

While I was moving a large file (~95GB) via the Caja file manager, and it crashed in the middle of the copy, stopping the operation entirely. Now I'm stuck with two separate files, the first is ~25GB, and the second is ~70GB.

Is there anything I can do to 'magically' turn it back into one?

Comment: Sorry?! Since when does a mv mess with the original file before it is moved over to the new location?!  1. Only the name in the directory entry gets changed if the move done on the same partition 2. If the target is on another partition, the data will first get copied to the target and then removed from source.  If what you claim is true for Caja file manager I would strongly advice to file a bug report and stay the hell away from it until fixed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of running `ls -l` on the original file and the new one. Also tell us if you were copying to/from the same disk, same partition, whether it was copying over a network. Basically give us as much detail as you can. The kind of file you are using and the filesystems involved are also very relevant.  It's quite likely you can fix this by simply running `cat file1 file2 >  newfile` but we'd need more detail to be sure.

Comment: Some things to note: you can not just simply compare sizes if the systems are different: NTFS and EXT can be formatted with different options making for different sizes for the same file. Next:  could it be possible the original file was changed during the move? And the change was to delete roughly 25Gb.

Comment: @terdon Unfourtunately, I'm unable to even investigate that, since it seemed to be a sign of hard drive failure. The disk became unreadable in the middle of the copy and Caja crashed. The one disk with half of the file is dead. (Sorry for the delay. I wanted to make sure the short was contained to the hard drive, so my computer has been out of service)

Answer (score 0):

[cat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cat.1.html) can do that for you.

```
$ cat partA partB > allParts
```

This will take a while with such large files. Also you need to check, if the  Caja file manager didn't lose any data while crashing.

Comment: Before doing this an investigation is in order. If the original file actually was 70 and not 95Gb allParts with have an extra 25Gb. A file split into 2 when doing a mv should be IMPOSSIBLE. The original file should always stay on the system until the system did a sanity check if the file is actually moved.